# Is there a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R} $ like $A$ such that the set of accumulation points of $A$ is itself and $A\cap\mathbb{Q} = \emptyset $

Tags: general-topology

Is there a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R} $ like $A$ such that the set of accumulation points of $A$ is $A$ and $A\cap\mathbb{Q}=\emptyset\,$?

Comment: What you mean is not «that accumulation points of $A$ is $A$» but «that the set of accumulation points of $A$ is $A$».

Comment: Another example (in addition to those found in the link) is one similar to the [generalized Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) in which we remove progressively smaller neighborhoods of rational numbers in $[0,1]$.